# Cannot access Github API using Curl in Gradle

Tags: git, curl, github, gradle

I am trying to access GitHub API to fetch commits from a particular repository. I am using `curl` command in `gradle`.

Problem:
The same curl command which is successfully executing/working from command-line is failing in gradle task.

Command:

```
curl  -X GET -H "Authorization:token <TOKEN>" https://api.github.com/repos/<reponame_with_slash>/commits
```

The strange part is that this command is smoothly working on command-line but not in gradle script. Here is my gradle code.

Gradle Code:

```
def command = "curl  -X GET -H \"Authorization:token <TOKEN>\" https://api.github.com/repos/<reponame_with_slash>/commits"

println command
def proc = command.execute()

proc.waitFor()
if (proc.exitValue() != 0) {
 println "stderr: ${proc.err.text}"
   println "stdout: ${proc.in.text}"
   throw new GradleException("failed with return code " + proc.exitValue())
   }
println proc.text
```

Comment: You can (and should) accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got the clue.

The problem was with concatenation. I just recoded that line like

`['curl','-X','POST',<url>,'-H',<authHeader>,'-d',<payload>].execute().text`

and it worked.